# Regex look for string which may contain whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the form:

```
absdaskk adknksadn daksnksa &gt; words words words &gt;
```

I would like to have a pattern which returns me ''words words words''. I'm sure I can do this using a regular expression, I tried using:

```
"&gt [A-Za-z\s] &gt"
```

but this gives me no results, I'm pretty sure the problem is with the whitespaces, which I think are represented by `\s`, but probably aren't..

Note: I may not use something like split, as the full string may contain more &gt parts, which is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `;`. Also, you need to throw in a `+` to ensure more than one character is matched.

```
&gt; [A-Za-z\s]+ &gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find whitespace, you can either use `\s` as well as literally a blank space , both works fine so there's no space issue in your code.

The problem is `[A-Za-z\s]` is only referring to 1 character which can be either `A-Z`, `a-z` or `\s`, but we need to refer to zero or more. So we need a `*` after these like this:

```
[A-Za-z\s]*
```

also, you forgot a semicolon after `&gt`. Note that if you are referring to content between `&gt;`, then to get them, you need capture group.

```
&gt;([A-Za-z\s]*)&gt;
```